# Should I worry that my battery Cycle Count is 1215?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, charging

I almost always have my laptop on charge since I work at a desk. I recently notice "service recommended" warning (it might have been there for some time)

is there something really wrong and to worry about? Or would I be ok to keep using this MacBook since I don't need to use it un-plugged.

We've been thinking of buying a MacBook Air for my father, he would only use to browse FaceBook and write his book. I use my MacBook way too much - for personal web dev projects, entertainment ...

would giving this to dad and me buying a new one be a good idea or is this still a good laptop for me (I absolutely love it, if I didn't just read about battery cycles I wouldn't have noticed anything)

[image]

Comment: I would be far more concerned with the fact that it's only charging to around 60% of what it did from the factory. I'd recommend replacing the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is no need to replace the battery unless

1. You are facing usage issues (such as the machine turning off before the battery is at 0%) or you're unhappy with your battery life
2. The battery is swollen (you'd usually notice if the bottom case starts bending and the Mac doesn't sit straight on the table anymore).

In the case of a swollen battery - that could be a potential safety hazard and the battery shouldn't be charged anymore and replaced immediately.

In the special case of your MacBook model (15", Mid 2015) there are models with faulty batteries, in which case Apple would replace them for free. You can check if your device is eligible on https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall

Comment: I have made an appointment for battery recall, thanks. I'm going to use my brother's early 2015 model. His battery cycle seems to be in the same range as mine but has no warning signs. We are planning to give it to my father (just for browsing). You're saying we can safely ignore the count and if we see "service recommended" as long as those two issues don't come up?

Comment: Issue (1) is usage-based really, if you can live with the poor battery life or knowing it will turn of at x% there's no reason to get it replaced either. It's only (2) you should be worried about, as it's a potential safety hazard.

Answer (score 2):

All laptop batteries age, and wither, and die, and it's this that affects the continued viability of the computer. You've had that one for over 5 years, and it is only holding 60% of its original capacity.

If you mainly intend to use it plugged in, then then it's not really a problem, though the battery will continue to degrade. The computer does need a working battery to function properly: without it, it will throttle the CPU. There is a teeny-tiny risk that as it continues to degrade, it could catch fire or explode, *(though presumably, if it's not holding much energy...:lol: )*

My advice would be to take it to an Apple Store. Apple will replace the battery for around $200, I think. You will then have a laptop that's 'as good as new', which will work reliably for another 5 years or so, either for you, or your Father.